# In Nuxt 3, how to enable highlight on page content?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, highlight, nuxtjs3

How exactly do I allow users to highlight content that is on the page?

On other pages for the app, they are able to highlight and copy to clipboard freely but for some reason on the main landing page which is the home page, they cant. I cant figure out why, could anyone please help?

I assume there's something blocking the text which is what is preventing the left click drag from highlighting the page but I cant figure out what is actually blocking the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is likely due to the css rule `user-select: none;`.

To check if your text element has it, follow these steps:

1. Open the browser devtools console, "Elements" tab to inspect the dom.
2. Select any text element you want to highlight but you can't
3. Make a search on this element's applied css (on the "Styles" tab) with `user-select`.
4. Check if this element has a `user-select: none;` applied (directly or inherited).
5. Try to remove that rule from your css.

Comment: Thank you. You were right, one of the senior developers had implemented that css rule that I had to remove to allow highlighting.